# Json.load() , Json.loads() is not working in python 2.7

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I want to use `json` library and run the code

```
import json

data = ''' {
    "name" : "Chuck",
    "phone": {
    "type" : "intl",
    "number" : "+1 734 355 4544"
     }
     "email" :{
     "hide" : "yes"
     } 
} '''

info = json.load(data)
print 'Name : ', info["name"]
print 'Hide:' , info["email"]["hide"]
```

It is showing the error **"return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
"**
Any solution for it? 
*Edited version*

Comment: You're using the wrong function. `json.load(fp)` is for a file stream. You should use `json.loads(s)` for a string.

Comment: You also need a comma separating the two dicts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've named your program `json.py` which conflicts with the built-in module `json`.

Rename your program to `my_program.py` and delete `json.py` and `json.pyc` from your directory.

Comment: It worked but a jiffy problem is that it giving the error in importing the json "ImportError: cannot import name json"

Comment: I don't know why that happens.

Comment: @Ali look at the comment by Nayuki.  Also your json string (data) is not valid json.